# В базе данных phpMyadmin datetime отображается нулями 0:00:00 .Как сделать так,чтобы выводилось реальное время?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

В базе данных phpMyadmin datetime отображается нулями 0:00:00 .Как сделать так,чтобы выводилось реальное время?если выставляю в таблице timespawn дата и время выводятся,но с отставанием в 7 часов.

Comment: Это не отставание, это время в UTC.

Comment: Подскажите.пожалуйста,я уже вставлял и в php timezone и на сервере в php.ini подобный код и ничего не помогает.Если есть образец того,как и куда можно прописать данные изменения,буду весьма признателен.

Comment: Что не помогает? Время в UTC - это нормальное поведение.

Comment: мне это нужно для того,чтобы время после получать в админку инетернет магазина в реальном времени

Comment: @АндрейАкимов, так php.ini - это php. а phpmyadmin - это mysql. Насколько я понимаю, Вам нужно исполнить команду `SET time_zone = '+07:00';` - это, например, если у Вас часовой пояс +7 от UTC.

Comment: Александр,а подскажите.пожалуйста,куда именно я должен вставить данный код.ведь я что-то подобное уже вставлял в php.Конкретно,я пытаюсь прикрутить на сайт форму обратного звонка.у меня имеется файл обработчик  и файл с подключением к базе данных.вот к какому из них,скажите,пожалуйста.

Comment: вы бы для начала показали код с помощью которого вставляете данные в БД. Как туда время попадает.

Comment: сейчас пришлю код,но что-то я в нем с датой ничего не делал,просто создал в базе данных строку в нужной таблице и в этой строке отображается дата с отставанием в 7 часов

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m4yud24q/

Comment: @АндрейАкимов, это, конечно, очень интересный вопрос - куда нужно исполнить команду MySQL?) вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-do-i-set-the-time-zone-of-mysql) подробнее. Затем останется всего-лишь исправить уже вставленные данные.